# Measure current through a very high DC voltage load

Tags: current-measurement, high-voltage

I want to measure the current of a 2kV DC which exceeds to 4kV at no load. The current is around 0.8mA. Can any one suggest a technique to do this? I can not use low-side current measurement as the load is grounded and cannot be altered.

Comment: Other than a current clamp?

Comment: yes, i want it in the form of voltage at a test point

Comment: Its D.C. SO a normal current clamp wouldn't work, but something like a closed loop hall-effect sensor would be OK.

Comment: but hall-effect sensors like ACS (allegro) ones doesn't provide such large voltage range.

Comment: 2KV at 8 amps? That's 16000 watts. What on earth are you doing? If something goes wrong, whatever it is will *probably* kill someone.

Comment: sorry its 0.8mA want it as 8V

Comment: Use a high voltage cable though an COTS hall effect current sensor.

Comment: @user8953 You MUST specify, tolerance to error, time characteristics , frequency, linearity, offset , temp. resolution, accuracy or SNR etc. # How may be trivial  or at least possible.# but that depends on above. Answers without some of these, are opinions based on speculation or false assumptions. So learn how to spec a requirement, please.

Comment: i.e is it important to measure dv/dc as I goes to zero or what is Imin accuracy needed.?  Physical and environment constraints are also necessary. Without these specs your requirement cannot be met with good engineering principles or any design. When you have done this I'll remove my -1

Comment: Measure the resistance of the load. Your supply voltage changes with that load. So supply voltage will work as an amp meter when using the load as the amp meter shunt.

Comment: You might also consider the fact that there is a current-dependent surface charge on a wire, which is required to cause the current you observe. The charge is tiny. But at least you can see the effect here: https://youtu.be/8BQM_xw2Rfo (from the Wiezmann Institute in Israel.) Since this charge depends upon current (less charge is required for lower current, more for higher current), it may be possible to consider an electrostatic method. There may be papers on the topic to research for another method to consider.

Answer (score 1):

It's "easy enough" if you are willing to power it with a battery or similar floating supply.

Measure current then convert to digital (best) but analog may be OK.
Then couple to ground reference with n isolated or voltage agnostic method.
These could included IR, RF, inductive, capacitive, ...

Hall sensors can have arbitrarily large isolation based mainly on insulation used. Just an airgap would be acceptable if you can guarantee a contamination free environment. The low current means that magnetic field from a "single turn" as is usually used with Hall sensors would be small, but  it may be acceptable to use a multi turn indductor to increase field strength.

[Digikey listing of optoisolators](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/isolators/special-purpose/3736395?FV=fff40039%2Cfff8034b&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=-597&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&k=opto+isolator&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500)  listed in descending order of isolation voltage. Top is 5 kV RMS but also obsolete.

In stock Digikey digital receiver UL rated 3750 kV RMS 1 minute [HCPL-2602, HCPL-2612](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV01-0568EN) - note that the UL rating is NOT a spec sheet rating - but also is lower than it will achieve in real life.This needs to be used with a digital signal.

[Magnetically couple digital isolators](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/isolators/digital-isolators/3736104?FV=fff40039%2Cfff80228&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=-597&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500) with 5 kV to 7.5 kV RMS datasheet specified isolation

'Just for fun'  7.5 kV isolation 2 channel bidirectional transceiver, 12 Mbps USB2 - [**LTM2894 datasheet**](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/2894f.pdf)
Uses inductive coupling.

**______________________________**

**Powering:**

A "solar panel / photovoltaic cell could be used for powering.
Overall the following is adequately pessimistic as to easily achieve the desired power output.

I've assumed that

- 50% of LED light is used by the PV panel.
- LED electrical to light efficiency of  20% - low for a good modern LED (around 50%).
- 15% PV module efficiency is good but realistic.
- 5W LED is 50% more than calculated with above assumptions.

To provide say 5V at 10 mA = 50 mW.
PV efficiency say 15%
LED efficiency say 20% (eg modern high efficiency white)
Light  usage say 50%.
Power  in = Pout /(Z_PV x Z_LED x Z_usage()
=  50 mW /(0.15 x 0.2 x 0.5) = 3.333W.
Say 5W LED rated at 150 l/W +

Available light = 5W x 0.2 = 1 Watt em energy
PV 100% rating = 1000 W/m^2 so 1W em energy drives 1/1000 m^2.
So say 0.05m x 0.1m = 50mm x 100mm silicon crystalline PV panel with module efficiency of > 15%.
PV power =

Answer (score 0):

How large resources are you ready to put into this project? The combination of high isolation voltage and low current makes measurements really complex.

The reliable solution is in using Flux Gate DC current transducer. It operates as DC current transformer with good isolation functionality. You get DC current output at "ground" potential. This current is exactly proportional to the primary current coupled to measurement ring of Flux Gate transducer.

You can search Google for this component. Its price is high, starting at several hundreds US$.

However: commercial transducers (as far as I know) typically measure currents over 20 A. There current transfer ratio is 1:500 or higher. So they convert your 0.8 mA to 1.6 uA. This signal will be clearly blurred by a noise.

You can still use such sensors by making many turns (at least 100) of "primary" wire over the Flux Gate sensor. This wire by itself must have isolation sufficient to withstand 5 kV. It is doable, taking into account (1) the small current and (2) large hole of Flux Gate sensors. The current transfer ratio will be 1:5 in this case. It makes 0.16 mA, that is easy to measure.